# How do you specify a minimum required version with the Mozilla addon-sdk cfx tool?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

Building a traditional Firefox extension, you would set the minVersion field in the install.rdf. Since that is abstracted away by package.json and cfx, is there any way to set a minVersion?

Motivation:
Because of certain changes to behavior in the contextMenu API, my add-on only works as expected from a certain versions of the Addon-SDK and upwards. I'd like to enforce this constraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Add-on SDK docs
[Changing minVersion and maxVersion Values](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/firefox-compatibility.html#Changing%20minVersion%20and%20maxVersion%20Values)

Comment: Is there any way to make Firefox respect these values? Due to the "Compatible By Default" behavior, firefox wont stop the user from installing incompatible add-ons. Can this be prevented?